# Sort NSArray with array of index numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
NSArray *needSortedArray = @[@"Alex", @"Rachel", @"Mohamad"];
```

and an array of index like this:

```
NSArray *indexArray = @[@1, @0, @2];
```

So the output I want will look like this:

```
needSortedArray = @[@"Rachel", @"Alex", @"Mohamad"];
```

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    NSArray *unsortedArray = @[@"Alex", @"Rachel", @"Mohamad"];
    NSArray *indexArray = @[@1, @0, @2];

    NSMutableArray * sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:unsortedArray.count];
    for (NSNumber * num in indexArray)
    {
        [sortedArray addObject:[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:num.integerValue]];
    }

   //now sortedArray has sorted objects.
```

Comment: Good solution if indexes are not equal and in correct indexes range for unsortedArray.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that supports any comparable types of indexes:

```
NSArray<NSString*> *unsortedArray = @[@"Alex", @"Rachel", @"Mohamad", @"Andrew"];
NSArray<NSNumber*> *indexArray = @[@1, @12, @23, @12];

NSParameterAssert([indexArray count] == [unsortedArray count]);
NSArray* sorted = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSNumber* index1 = indexArray[[unsortedArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:obj1]];
    NSNumber* index2 = indexArray[[unsortedArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:obj2]];

    NSComparisonResult result = [index1 compare:index2];
    return result;
}];

NSLog(@"Sorted array: %@", sorted);
```